# Cant access to file array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js

cant access the elements of the file array

```
  const p_page = postP.new_pages;
  const p_page_o = postP.new_pages_order;
  const p_page_o_len = p_page_o.length;
  if (p_page_o_len > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < p_page_o_len; i++) {
      console.log(p_page);  //Returns array with files inside it
      console.log(p_page[0]);  //returns undefined 
      console.log(p_page[i]);  //returns undefined

      formData.append("pages[]", p_page[i]);
      formData.append("pages_order[]", p_page_o[i]);
    }
  }
```

And when i try to console log them :

[image]

Edit: what i am trying to do here is basically i am putting image files in a array and before post them to the backend putting together in a formdata through loop, i can see the p_page console log, but i cant access the first or anyother child in the array, throws undefined. Sorry for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but this just solve it:

```
  const p_page_o_len = postP.new_pages_order.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < p_page_o_len; i++) {

    const page = postP.new_pages[i];
    formData.append("pages[]", page);

    const order = postP.new_pages_order[i];
    formData.append("pages_order[]", order);

  }
```

I appreciative for everyone, and sorry for the bad explanation. Still cant understand whats problem with it, but at least its solved for me.